# How can I redefine normal font as semi-bold in xetex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, font-encodings

Here is the Latex code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{extarticle}
    
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \color{Maroon}
    Hello!
    Here the math: $3^2+4^2=5^2$.
    
    \end{document}
```

I would like make normal fonts in text and in math bolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`, option `T1` and the package `fontenc` are not required, instead of that, it's better to use `fontspec` package and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}
\mathversion{bold}%this change bold in Math
    \color{Maroon}
    Hello!
    Here the math: $3^2+4^2=5^2$.
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear and thanks for letting me know